# Force change/reset mysql password?

Tags: mysql, database, mamp

I'm having trouble with my MAMP installation where I can't seem to connect to the database.

I thought I knew the password, but it doesn't work and I can't log into mysql manually with it.

I want to hard reset the root password for the MAMP installation of mysql, can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start mysql with [`--skip-grant-tables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables) to bypass the login system. that'll let you in as a superuser, and you can modify user accounts.

Afterwards, use `flush privileges` to restore the access control system.

Comment: 'sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --skip-grant-tables' (abd without sudo) returns 'unknown option '--skip-grant-tables''

Comment: unless your mysql was compiled to disable the command-line grant options, that command should be available, as per the linked docs.

Answer (score 0):

Type this in your terminal:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password <YOUR_PASS>
```

If your password not working, use flush privileges

Comment: no joy, the password fails. Where should I use flush privileges?

Comment: '/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root --skip-grant-tables
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin: unknown option '--skip-grant-tables''

Comment: Try : mysqld -u root --skip-grant-tables

Comment: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.